# MySQL Query avoid usage of variable

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to put the first query into the main query and to avoid set of a variable?

```
SET @domain_id = (SELECT id FROM stop_domain LIMIT 1);
SELECT
  IFNULL(MAX(duid), 0) + 1 AS duid
  , @domain_id
FROM
  stop_link
WHERE domain_id = @domain_id;
```

stop_domain

```
id | url
```

stop_link

```
id | duid | domain_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT     IFNULL(MAX(duid), 0) + 1 AS duid
           ,t.id
FROM       (SELECT id FROM stop_domain LIMIT 1) t
INNER JOIN stop_link
ON         domain_id = t.id
GROUP BY   t.id;
```

Comment: this shows: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 't.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is,

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(MAX(duid), 0) + 1 AS duid
  , domain_id
FROM
  stop_link
WHERE domain_id = (SELECT id FROM stop_domain LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: This shows In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'stop_link.domain_id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by